# How to set Babel option compact to false without eject in create-react-app-project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

While loading a big dataset I get webpack error: 
"[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "C: ... src/data/bigdataset.js" as it exceeds the max of '500KB'.".

I suppose that setting babel option "compact" to "false" in Webpack's query parameter would solve my issue, but how do I do it in project created by "create-react-app" without using eject? 
(Ejecting isn't option in this case...)

Comment: Have you tried to create a `.babelrc` file in your root directory ?

`
{
"compact": false
}
`

If you don't want to create a `.babelrc` file you can set the configuration in the package.json:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc.html

Comment: @sanghin Those don't seem to work with create-react-app without ejecting.